# can not invoke Equals method on the primitives->Override Equals method not working -beginner 's mistake in Java

Tags: java, overriding

I obtained compiling errors when overriding the Equals method more specifically at Float and Double parentheses, weight and price attributes, the HashCode method seems to work, so I don't know where the problem is in my code. The code also contains an interface Vehicle, but I don't expect the error to be from the interface. I am not sure if I understood entirely the Equals method . Can someone help me?

```
 package info.vehicle;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    public class Car implements Vehicle,Serializable,Cloneable {
    private float weight;
    private double price;
    private String producer;


    public Car()
    {

    }

    public Car(float _weight,double _price,String _producer)
    {
     weight=_weight;
     price=_price;
     producer=_producer;
    }

    public void setProducer(String _producer) throws Exception
    {
        if(_producer!=null && _producer.length()>1)
            this.producer=_producer;

    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Producer must not be null.");
    }
    }

    public void setPrice(double _price) throws Exception
    {
        if(_price>0)
        {
            price=_price;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Price must not be 0.");
        }
    }

    public void setWeight(float _weight) throws Exception
    {
        if(weight>0)
        {
            weight=_weight;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Weight must be different than 0.");
        }

    }

    @Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Car other=(Car)obj;
    if(((Float)(this.weight)).equals(Float)other.weight)
    {

    if((Double)(this.price)).equals((Double)other.price))
       {
        if(this.producer.contentEquals(other.producer))
          {
             return super.equals(obj);
          }
       }
    }

    return false;
} 

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Car temp=new Car();
        temp.weight=this.weight;
        temp.price=this.price;
        temp.producer=this.producer;
        return temp;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime=31;
        int result=0;
        result+=(int)weight*prime;
        result+=(int)price*prime;
        result+=producer.length()*prime;
        return result;
    }






        @Override
        public String infoVehicle() {

            return producer;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What exactly are the compiling errors? Can you add the error message? Also it would really help if you would format the equals method so that one can more easily see which block belongs in which parenthesis.

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Comment: Joshua Bloch tells you how to override equals and hashCode properly in "Effective Java" chapter 3: http://fpl.cs.depaul.edu/jriely/ds2/extras/Chapter3.pdf

Comment: I would discourage you from implementing Serializable and Cloneable interfaces.  Your teacher is asking you to do things that current day practitioners don't do.  No one serializes to Java byte code; better to serialize to JSON or XML.  Better to write a copy constructor than to clone; that's a 1995 vintage interface that introduced lots of problems.  No one does that anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple syntax errors.

```
equals(Float)other.weight)
```

Should be

```
equals((Float) other.weight)
```

and

```
if((Double)(this.price))
```

should be

```
if(((Double)(this.price))
```

But why are you explicitly casting them?

Comment: @Corina mmh okay. Well you got your fix at least :)

Comment: @Corina if you really have to cast them, use the primitive ones (float, double), not the wrapper ones (Float, Double).

Comment: thank you verry much, your instructions really saved me time and nerves, and sorry for not upvoting the answer before you told me to .

Comment: @Corina no problem, don't worry about it.